# zf2 - getting controller plugins in form/controller factory

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-servicemanager

Is it possible to access controller plugins from a form/controller factory (any factory implementing FactoryInterface)?

I have a form factory that i want to set the form action depending on the request parameter, but need to access the url from the route defined in config.

So whereas in a controller i would use the url controller plugin:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url()->fromRoute('appointment.add', array('clientId' => $clientId)));
```

...how can i access this in a factory? eg something like:

```
class MyFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface  $serviceLocator){
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        //...snip...
        $form = new AddAppointmentForm($client);
        $serviceManager->get('ControllerPluginManager');
        $url =  $controllerPluginManager->get('Url');
        die($url->fromRoute('appointment.add', ['clientId' => $clientId]));
        return $form;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be good practice to use controller plugins in a non controller context.
To assemble an URL with the ZF2 router you could just use the router which is also available in the `ServiceManager`.

```
$router = $serviceManager->get('HttpRouter');
$url = $router->assemble(['clientId' => $clientId], ['name' => 'appointment.add']);
```

Comment: Excellent, that's what i was hoping for. I agree with your principle of the plugin being used outside of a controller context, however thought there may be a universal/base url helper, like the available view helper. Using the HttpRouter is ideal, thanks.

Comment: A more sustainable way is to refactor your form factory into a Service.  Instantiate it via a Service Factory, passing in the service manager.  Just a practice hint, been there, done that -- we moved to setting the action attribute at the controller level -- there are some edge cases that the router will not contain current information, and future support effort will be less.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance of \Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager in your factory and can easily get url or whatever plugin you want. Just a little problem, you can't set your controller in you plugin manager. So, controller dependent plugin will NOT work properly.